# Multiple users, single laptop, private and shared software

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, lamp, multi-user

I have 2 users on my laptop: "work" and "private". Now I want to add a third user "experiment" on which I want to experiment with other software.

To be more precise: I want "experiment" to automatically start a LAMP-server, but both other users do not need this at all. I do not want to have lamp-server running when I am "work" or "private".

How to achieve this?

sigridt

PS because of lack of memory I always logout when switching user

Comment: "LAMP-server"? Not a single user kind of thing, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29 the Wikipedia entry. Also, "Lack of memory" will really slow you down.

Comment: Typically services run as a seperate user, e.g www-data for apache, and are started and stopped with the system. The *easiest* would be to simply start and stop the service manually (`sudo service apache2 start` and `sudo service apache2 stop`).